# Powershell cmdlet returns no results (sometimes, intermittently)

Tags: powershell

Disclaimer: I know there are other ways to perform this function - this was more of a learning Powershell syntax exercise:

I wanted to use Get-ADGroup to find groups where the property "Members" contains "Employee X" (a unique name) and currently if I run this:

```
Get-ADGroup -filter * -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.Members -like "*Employee X*"}
```

I get results... however, yesterday as I was trying various permutations of the command, that exact syntax was not working:  I was receiving nothing (aka no error, just a new PS screen prompt immediately after).  Which led me to believe I had the syntax wrong.

Today as I was about to open this question, I tried it and it worked (various AD group objects returned with the criteria).  I thought I surely must have mistyped - for example, you have to include "-Properties *" in order to include the "Members" property to pipe against.  But as I was showing this to someone today, walking through my thought process and subsets of the command, it happened again:  The exact same command returned with no results, just a new PS prompt.  And then after a few more variations, I came back to the same command and it included results.

Is this a bug?  Is there a time-out?  I'm not assigning it to a variable - this is a direct cmdlet execution in Windows Powershell 5.1.17763.316 console on Windows 10.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible the domain controller or ldap server you are querying is having issues? If you add the `-server` parameter with a known good AD server, do you still get intermittent results. When there are issues with the command, can you run `Get-ADDomainController` and see if the output differs from when the command works as expected vs when it does not?

Comment: Hmm- that's an interesting point - it's plausible the command isn't finding an AD server or timing out on the request to a specific one.  I would have thought they'd throw an error in that case though.  I can't reproduce the issue consistently enough to test (it's working flawlessly right now), but if I can get it to happen again I'll try -server parameter.   thanks for the idea!